# Heroku Stopped Responding To Requests Overnight, And Now It Only Works if I Turn On A VPN (I Live in Syria)

Tags: node.js, flutter, heroku

Heroku Is Ristricted in Syria But APIs Work From AnyWhere,
Overnight The Front-End APP Stopped Getting Requests From The API Our Employer Hosted From The US.
I Checked The Heroku Logs And Its Not Registring Any Requests Sent To It But When i Turn On Any Type Of VPN The App Works Perfectly.
APi is Nodejs and Front-End is Flutter
Searched All Over The Internet For A Sloution With No Luck,
Even Moved The API To A Europe Dyno And It Didn't Work.
I Did not Find ANy Documentation About Heroku Dynos Being Blocked From Syria,
Any Advice?
The Release is Due And Im Unable TO Make it Work
PS:Sorry For Bad English

Comment: Syria has blocked large portions of the internet in the past. There's not much you, we, or Heroku can do about this.

Comment: Just Heard About it, They Banned Hosting Services Outside Syria.

Comment: Thanks For Your Response

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.